# Sharing an instance of a class with related classes

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have a group of classes which inherit from the  `ConfigurationSection` class. I also have a `Logger` class which I use to create individual log files for each class, but this does not yet include these configuration classes.

Instead of creating a new instance of `Logger` (and as a result, a new log file) for each of these `ConfigurationSection` classes, I want them all to use the same instance, and log to the same file.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Here are a few options that I've considered.

---

#### Pass an instatiated Logger as a parameter when instantiating each of the related classes

This seems like the most obvious option, but I really dont like it. My `Logger` class isnt exactlt lightweight, and I'd prefer to refrain from passing such large parameters around. Regardless, it's an option.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        // These variables are used for illustrative purposed,
        // instead of showing my `Logger' class
        bool loggerInstantiated = true;
        DateTime InstantiatedTime = DateTime.Now;

        DerivedClass01 dc01 = new DerivedClass01( loggerInstantiated, InstantiatedTime );

        // added to create delay between the instantiation of different derived classes
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 1000 );

        DerivedClass02 dc02 = new DerivedClass02( loggerInstantiated, InstantiatedTime );
    }
}


class BaseClass : ConfigurationSection
{
    public BaseClass( bool loggerInstantiated, DateTime instantiatedAt )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("BaseClass:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", loggerInstantiated, instantiatedAt ) );
    }
}

class DerivedClass01 : BaseClass
{ 
    public DerivedClass01( bool loggerInstantiated, DateTime instantiatedAt ) : base(loggerInstantiated, instantiatedAt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "DerivedClass01:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", loggerInstantiated, instantiatedAt ) );
    }
}

class DerivedClass02 : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass02( bool loggerInstantiated, DateTime instantiatedAt ) : base( loggerInstantiated, instantiatedAt )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "DerivedClass02:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", loggerInstantiated, instantiatedAt ) );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/*
BaseClass:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:16:09

DerivedClass01:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:16:09

BaseClass:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:16:09

DerivedClass02:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:16:09
*/
```

Conclusion:

This is certainly an option. each class that's derived from `BaseClass` would be able to use the same `Logger`. But due to the size of my `Logger` class, I think it's best not to pass this entire instance as a parameter.

Edit:

As pointed out by @Malior and @ScottHannen, I was completely misunderstanding what actually happens when you hass an instance of a class as a parameter. My reasons for not wanting to do this are now somewhat invalid, but I'd still rather not have to pass the `Logger` as a parameter whenever instantiating a class derived from `BaseClass`.

---

#### Inherit from a base class

Create a `BaseClass` which inherits from `ConfigurationSection`, and have the instantiated `Logger` on the `BaseClass`. Any related `ConfigurationSection` classes can inherit from this `BaseClass`.

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        DerivedClass01 dc01 = new DerivedClass01();

        // added to create delay between the instantiation of different derived classes
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 1000 );

        DerivedClass02 dc02 = new DerivedClass02();
    }
}

class BaseClass : ConfigurationSection
{
    // These variables are used for illustrative purposed,
    // instead of showing my `Logger' class
    public bool LoggerInstantiated;
    public DateTime InstantiatedAt;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        LoggerInstantiated = true;
        InstantiatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("BaseClass:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", LoggerInstantiated, InstantiatedAt));
    }
}

class DerivedClass01 : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass01()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "DerivedClass01:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", LoggerInstantiated, InstantiatedAt ) );
    }
}

class DerivedClass02 : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass02()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "DerivedClass02:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", LoggerInstantiated, InstantiatedAt ) );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/*
BaseClass:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:21:51

DerivedClass01:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:21:51

BaseClass:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:21:52

DerivedClass02: 
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:21:52
*/
```

Conclusion:

This is no good. A new instance `Logger` would be created every time a derived class is instantiated (which is fairly obvious - I should have realised sooner...)

---

#### Inherit from a base class containing a static Logger

Similar to above, but instead of instance `Logger`, have a static one. Create it before instantiating the `DerivedClasses`, and do not create a new instance within the `BaseClass` constructor.

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {

        BaseClass.LoggerInstantiated = true;
        BaseClass.InstantiatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        DerivedClass01 dc01 = new DerivedClass01();

        // added to create delay between the instantiation of different derived classes
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 1000 );

        DerivedClass02 dc02 = new DerivedClass02();
    }
}

class BaseClass : ConfigurationSection
{
    // These variables are used for illustrative purposed,
    // instead of showing my `Logger' class
    public static bool LoggerInstantiated;
    public static DateTime InstantiatedAt;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("BaseClass:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", LoggerInstantiated, InstantiatedAt));
    }
}

class DerivedClass01 : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass01()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "DerivedClass01:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", LoggerInstantiated, InstantiatedAt ) );
    }
}

class DerivedClass02 : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass02()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "DerivedClass02:\n\r\tLoggerInitiated is {0} at {1}\n\r", LoggerInstantiated, InstantiatedAt ) );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/*
BaseClass:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:05:56

DerivedClass01:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:05:56

BaseClass:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:05:56

DerivedClass02:
    LoggerInitiated is True at 21/12/2018 14:05:56
*/
```

Conclusion:

This seems like a reasonable option. Each class derived from `BaseClass` will have access to the same `Logger`, without having to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Why don't you make the logger a static class and use it everywhere without instantiating it?

Comment: @NikhilVartak The question is the relevant part, which is only a few lines. The rest is just various options I have tried. Fell free to ignore them and provide me with some help based on my question. Thanks

Comment: @rashmatash Thats not a bad idea actually, but it would mean quite a change to alot of existing code. I think I prefer my third option (above) of having a static reference to an instantiated logger within the `BaseClass`, since thins means less change to existing code. Thanks

Comment: In your first sample, what do you mean by the size of the logger class? It's a class instance, and you only forward the pointer. this is not heavy.

Comment: Can you clarify this:  "But due to the size of my Logger class, I think it's best not to pass this entire instance as a parameter." What do you mean by the "size?" When you pass a reference to an object, you're just passing a pointer. It's not creating anything new or duplicating anything existing. So you might be concerned about something that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Malior, thanks for pointing this out - I actually didnt realise this. I assumed that, because passing an instance of a large class seems to take longer (than passing an instance of a very basic class) when stepping through with a debugger, that it actually slows down your application. I guess this isnt the case. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks for clarifying, didnt realise this (see my comment above if you're interested in why...). Thanks

Comment: You can make the Logger class a (Singleton) this design pattern will allow you to have one instance of Logger class that will be used by all the classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to define your logger as a singleton or as a static class. That creates problems with being able to test your code. There are other ways to ensure that all classes use the same instance.

I'd start with an interface. Write it so that it describes how you want your classes to use it, like this:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}
```

Then, inject it into your classes like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public YourClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    private void MethodThatDoesWhatever()
    {
        try
        {
            // do something
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Log(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You haven't written an implementation of `ILogger` yet, but that's the whole point. If your class can use `ILogger` even though there's no implementation, that means your class is entirely decoupled from the implementation of `ILogger`. It depends on an abstraction, which is dependency inversion.

How do you ensure that all of your classes use the same instance? If you're using a dependency injection container like Windsor, that might look something like this:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
    Component.For<ILogger, YourLoggerImplementation>(),
    Component.For<YourClass>(),
    Component.For<SomeOtherClassThatNeedsLogger>()
);
```

When you ask the container for an instance of `YourClass`,

```
var myClass = container.Resolve<YourClass>();
```

- it will attempt to create an instance of `YourClass`.
- It will determine that the constructor requires an `ILogger`.
- You told it that the component (class) to use for `ILogger` is `YourLoggerImplementation`, so it will create one of those and pass it to the constructor.
- Unless you tell it otherwise, it will not create a new instance of `YourLoggerImplementation`. It will just keep the same instance and reuse it, so now all of your classes use the same logger instance.

I've totally glossed over a lot about how to use an IoC container (Windsor, AutoFac, Unity, Ninject, ,NET `ServiceCollection`, more.) It's worth understanding, but it's beyond the scope of this answer. To learn more you'd need to start with the type of application that you're writing. For example, you would search for "use dependency injection with ASP.NET MVC" or "use dependency injection with WPF" because how you get started relates to the sort of application. (Even then I'm oversimplifying, but IMO it's better to start off that way. When you see an example tailored to the type of app you're working in it's more likely to click.)

Then you have to write the logger implementation itself. If it's writing to a file and multiple class instances are all using it, I'd recommend an implementation that puts messages in a `ConcurrentQueue`. Then when the queue reaches a certain size or at regular timer intervals (or both) you flush the messages out to the file. With a `ConcurrentQueue` multiple threads can add messages at the same time, and one thread can take messages out of the queue and write them to the file at the same time as other threads are writing new messages.

Comment: This sounds like a good way to go. I've never really used `interface`'s nor looked into Dependency Injection before, so I'll do some research on them. However, your description sounds like the exact kind of functionality I'm after, and even though it's pretty far from the idea I had in mind when asking the question, I think it's the most suitable answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @rashmatash. I have a logger myself that is static and it can be used anywhere. It can create new files and it can append to existing files.

The public method accepts and exception, optionally a custom message, and optionally a string of the full path of the desired log file.

```
public static void LogError(Exception Ex, string Message = null, string LogFile = null)
```

If LogFile is left null, a log file named ErrorLog.txt will be created/appended in the application base directory + \Logs.

Here is the main part:

```
if (LogFile == null || LogFile == String.Empty)
            {
                LogFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Logs\ErrorLog.txt";
            }

            string logDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(LogFile);
            int lineNo = GetExceptionLineNumber(Ex);
            string message = CreateMessageString(Ex, lineNo, Message);

            try
            {
                if (VerifyOrCreateDirectory(logDir) == true)
                {
                    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path: LogFile, append: true);

                    string logEntryHeaderInfo = DateTime.Now + " :: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToString() + " :: " + Environment.UserName + " :: " + Environment.MachineName;
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(logEntryHeaderInfo + " :: " + message);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: This sounds like a pretty good option. Could you please give an example of how you achieve this? I'm mainly querious about creating new files for each different class that uses the same logger. Thanks

Comment: Added more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton pattern

[Singleton Pattern C#](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton singleton= new Singleton();

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return singleton; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

So you can use the same instance in any part or your code:

```
var singleton= Singleton.Instance;
var foo = new Foo(singleton);
```

Or maybe you want to use a Dependency injection framework like Ninject, Unity, Simple Injector

Comment: A bit out of fasion in 2018, though? ... :o

Comment: @Sam it is pattern of development, it can't get old. Answer suggests using DI frameworks, it is quite modern way to use it

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo, Ehe, Hey - I happen to love a Singleton myself. Patterns do get old though and there's legit reasons why Singletons are off trend ( testablitiy ). DI would be an answer, But that has little to do with Singletons, and you wouldn't use a singleton service in for logging really? Just passing the object in as a ctor argument would allow a change to DI later, whereas the Singleton impl is going to be there for good...but it was just a thought, really :)

Comment: no singleton please. Even if it's must for a case, it should be thread safe. This one is not. Use `Lazy` class for private instance.

Comment: @Sam I agree with you :D was not focused that much on implementation/usage as on 'singleton' term itself

Comment: This is something I've never used before, and I find the concept pretty interesting. There's a couple of comment suggesting that a logger would not be great use for a singleton. I'm definitely going to keep this in mind for future work though